# Whole page flash ad removes ability to scroll

Tags: advertisements, flash, user-interface

When there's a whole page flash ad (so they can display the flash as an overlay over the content, and you have to click something to make it go away) the mouse focus is stolen.

The scroll wheel on the mouse then no longer works, and since it's a whole page flash ad, clicking elsewhere on the page doesn't move focus back to the content.

**Is there a way to put the focus back on the content so I can scroll with my mouse?**

Today it's on [failblog](http://failblog.org/) (and many of the other cheezburger network sites) with a car ad.

I'm loading flashblock now, but there will be some sites which I'll allow flash on that will do this occasionally, so I'm hoping there's a more general solution as well.

<sub>Firefox 3.6.8 on win7 64</sub>